# Can't load ggplots2 package through JRI

Tags: r, ggplot2, jri

I'm having issues loading the ggplot2 package through the JRI interface. ggplot2 loads fine through the R script, so I believe it has been installed properly. It is only when I attempt to load it through JRI when I get the following error.

```
Loading required package: reshape
Loading required package: plyr
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/R/lib/R/library/plyr/libs/plyr.so':
ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/R/lib/R/library/plyr/libs/plyr.so: symbol R_NilValue: referenced symbol not found
Error: package 'plyr' could not be loaded
```

So ggplot2 requires that the plyr package be loaded. This package will load if run by the R script, but will not from JRI. I suspect this is due to the fact that an environment variable is not being set correctly prior to loading JRI, perhaps an LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Looking at the R script I do not know where this path is set (since the R script apparently sets all environment variables correctly for plyr to find the needed R_NilValue symbol). I've copied all the environment variable settings from the R script into the script that I use to load JRI (so that it sets the R_HOME, R_SHARE_DIR, R_INCLUDE_DIR, and R_DOC_DIR correctly - I was having problems loading other packages through JRI as well until I set these environment variables, and it resolved those issues). However, this doesn't fix the error. Furthermore, I've tried loading the ggplots2 package from the rJava/JRI -provided Run script and I still get the same error. Can anyone tell me where the R_NilValue is defined, and what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running R version 2.13.0 on sparc-sun-solaris2.10 32 bit platform with packages rJava 0.9-0 and ggplot2 0.8.9.

Comment: For clarification, in my Java code I have the following line
 > re.eval("library(ggplot2)")

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is a mismatch in packages. In other words there are packages that were built for static R that are used with packages build for dynamic R. Reinstalling packages should fix this.